# EF Core Configure a object with generic type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following object:

```
public class Foo<TEntity>
{
   public int Id {get; set;}

   public ICollection<TEntity> Tasks {get; set;}
}
```

The type configuration for the above entity is:

```
public abstract class FooConfig<TEntity> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Foo<TEntity>>
{
   public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Foo<TEntity>> builder)
   {
      builder.ToTable("foo")

      builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
   }
}
```

I have 2 DbSet that use the abstract class (Bar and Spam has a many to one relation with Foo):

```
DbSet <Foo<Bar>> BarFoo    
DbSet <Foo<Spam>> SpamFoo
```

Their configurations are:

```
public class Bar
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public Foo<Bar> Foo { get; set; }
}

public class BarFooConfig : FooConfig<Bar>
{
   public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Foo<Bar>> builder)
   {
      base.Configure(builder);

      builder.HasMany(x => x.Tasks)
         .WithOne(x => x.Foo)
         .HasForeignKey(x => x.FooId)
   }
}

public class Spam
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public Foo<Spam> Foo { get; set; }
}

public class SpamFooConfig : FooConfig<Spam>
{
   public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Foo<Spam>> builder)
   {
      base.Configure(builder);

      builder.HasMany(x => x.Tasks)
         .WithOne(x => x.Foo)
         .HasForeignKey(x => x.FooId)
   }
}
```

But when I run the code I get the following error:

> Cannot use table 'Foo' for entity type 'Foo' since it is being used for entity type 'Foo' and there is no relationship between their primary keys

Please let me know if more details are needed

Comment: You may have to specify separate table names for each closed generic entity.

Comment: You want each row in the `foo` table to have a FK to a different table? You can define a TPH with an abstract base class, and generic sub-classes. EF Core will then filter the joins based on a discriminator column. But you may need to edit the migration to ignore any actual FKs.

Comment: Spam/Bar are separate entity/tables and each table has a FK reference to the Foo table.
In order to call/create Spam/Bar table I want to call Foo<Spam> or Foo<Bar> to specify which table will be created in relation to Foo

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care if a single `Foo` can have both `Bar` & `Spam` child records, then the simple answer is to just remove the generics and define two navigations.

```cs
public class Foo
{
   public int Id {get; set;}

   public ICollection<Spam> Spam {get; set;}
   public ICollection<Bar> Bar {get; set;}
}
```

Otherwise, you'll need to define a [table-per-heirachy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance), adding a discriminator [shadow] property to your foo table.

```cs
public abstract class Foo{
   public int Id {get; set;}
}

public class Foo<TEntity> : Foo{
   public ICollection<TEntity> Tasks {get; set;}
}
```

Then the rest of your example will probably just work without any further explicit configuration. Since EF Core will discover each `Foo<T>` used and configured in the rest of your model.

Then any time you query the navigation properties, EF Core will add a discriminator test to the sql join clause.

Though you can follow the documentation on how to define a discriminator explicitly instead of relying on EF Core to define a shadow property.

Answer (score 0):

**I was able to get a result with such a study.**

Define IGenericConfiguration:

```
public interface IGenericConfiguration<T> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T : BaseEntitiy
    {
        public void SpecialConfigure(EntityTypeBuilder<T> builder); 
    }
```

And Define GenericConfiguration:

```
 public abstract class GenericConfiguration<T> : IGenericConfiguration<T> where T : BaseEntitiy
 {
     public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<T> builder)
     {

         builder.Property(x => x.lastModifiedDate).HasColumnType("timestamp");
         builder.Property(x => x.createDate).HasColumnType("timestamp");

         SpecialConfigure(builder);
          
     }

     public virtual void SpecialConfigure(EntityTypeBuilder<T> builder) { }
 }
```

You can make the common conf settings in each part under the Config function of GenericConfiguration

Entity-specific configurations can be defined as follows:

```
  public class TestConfiguration : GenericConfiguration<Test>  
    {
        public override void SpecialConfigure(EntityTypeBuilder<Test> builder)
        {
            builder.Property(x => x.test).HasColumnType("VARCHAR(100)");
        }
    }
```

---

**Important**

You must be register your configuration files in OnModelCreating. Here is a method you can do this:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
 { 
     builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(GetType().Assembly); 
     base.OnModelCreating(builder);
 }
```

**Note 1:** It searches for all classes that have implemented the IEntityTypeConfiguration interface within the assembly, i.e., the given DLL, and automatically registers them all

**Note 2: This code block should be inside the DbContext object**